# Cleaning up a lock directory with bash.

Tags: bash, locking

after some reserch I have come across these code snipts for simple locking for a script i only want to run a single time.

```
    if ! mkdir /tmp/myscript.lock 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Myscript is already running." >&2
    exit 1
fi

function finish {
  rm -r /tmp/myscript.lock
}
trap finish EXIT
```

So part one attempts a lock dir and exits if the directory already exists.

Second bit of code is there so that if the script crashes or exits it then cleans up the directory so the script can restart.

My question is that if the script is already running and I start a second copy it will exit due to the lock file, but in the process will delete the lock directory?

Is there a way I can insure that if the script terminated due to the lock file presence it does not delete it, but if the script exits smoothly and or crahses during exicuation it cleans up the dir?

I dont want to use any other tools I am just curious how this can be achived, and i cant seem to find any examples of both used togather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to use `trap` for cleanup. Just make sure to do cleanup at the point of exit like this:

```
tmpFile='/tmp/myscript.lock'

if ! mkdir "$tmpFile" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Myscript is already running." >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "script is running..."
# script code starts here, sleep is just an example
sleep 20

# script complete, perform cleanup
rm -rf "$tmpFile"
echo "script completed..."
```

Now while this script is running all subsequent invocation of this script will exit with status=1 in the first `if` block without removing your lock file.

Comment: Sorry the script is a continual running script, it carries out a latency check on a server every 6 0seconds and logs the results. So the scipt should never exit. Once running at start up it will just keep looping. To this was more if the the script goes bad and crashes out that it will clean up the lock.

Comment: Thinking about it though maybe I am looking at this wrong and should jsut have cron run the script every 60 seconds. not use a loop

Comment: Yes, running this check from cron is definitely better instead of a forever running script